# make a list of service mocks to return desired value randomly?

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-stream

I have a service that has a list of other services

```
public class MyFrontService {
    @Autowired
    private Set<? extends MyAbstractService> allMyServices;
}
```

and it runs all the services in the set. Here is the signature for MyAbstractService

```
public abstract class MyAbstractService {
     boolean myMethod();
}
```

If any service in allMyServices returns false, then myFrontService returns false; it will only return true when all its services return true.

I am wondering how to unit test MyFrontService, using a Java 8 way. Ideally I can specify a number of services in the set to return true, while the others return false.

Any help/hints are deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Java 8 specific, but inside of your test framework, you could create "fake" test service classes that extend MyAbstractService, each of which deterministically succeed or fail. In these test classes, you could override the methods to produce specific results that MyFrontService would be checking.

Comment: I have created mocks in my test configuration and they are successfully injected into allMyServices. But I want to find a way to dynamically change the behavior of each mock in every test method, if possible. Right now I can only think of using the set iterator to traverse each and hopefully change them, feels awkward

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mockito in your test class for the service, maybe try:

```
MyAbstractService mockAbstractService1 = mock(MyAbstractService.class);
when(mockAbstractService1.myMethod()).thenReturn(true);
MyAbstractService mockAbstractService2 = mock(MyAbstractService.class);
when(mockAbstractService2.myMethod()).thenReturn(false); 

HashSet<MyAbstractService> abstractServices = new HashSet<MyAbstractService>();
abstractServices.Add(mockAbstractService1);
abstractServices.Add(mockAbstractService2);

MyFrontService testFrontService = new MyFrontService();
testFrontService.allMyServices = abstractServices;
```

Like that, you create Mocks (empty Object, has same functions and attributes like the Class you create it from, but does nothing unless you add a "when") and with the "when" you define, that each time the myMethod() of the object is called, it returns whatever you write in the thenReturn() of the when(). So each time you call myMethod() for mockAbstractService1, it returns true while myMethod for mockAbstractService2 returns false.